# Problema com Array para Json

Tags: php

Eu fiz uma requisição simples ao banco de dados e estou tentando passar esses dados para um json porém uma parte está sendo duplicada no JSON

**PHP:**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM UNIFORMS";

$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

$rows= array();

while($sonuc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $rows[id]=$sonuc[id];
    $rows[userid]=$sonuc[userid];
    $rows[uniform_type]=$sonuc[uniform_type];
    $rows[date]=$sonuc[date];
    $rows[size]=$sonuc[model];
    $rows[color]=$sonuc[color];
    $rows[provider_id]=$sonuc[provider_id];
    $rows[contract]=$sonuc[contract];
    $rows[amount]=$sonuc[amount];
    $rows[cost]=$sonuc[cost];
    $rows[place]=$sonuc[place];

    array_push($rows,$sonuc);
}

 echo json_encode($rows);
```

**Resposta:**

```
{…}0: Object { id: "30", userid: "YS3ul395jBDcBf8I", uniform_type: "Blazer", … }1: Object { id: "31", userid: "YS3ul395jBDcBf8I", uniform_type: "Blazer", … }2: Object { id: "32", userid: "YS3ul395jBDcBf8I", uniform_type: "Blazer", … }3: Object { id: "33", userid: "YS3ul395jBDcBf8I", uniform_type: "Blazer", … }amount: "10"color: "Preto"contract: "INCA"cost: "50"date: "2018-01-26 15:00:57"id: "33"place: "Nit"provider_id: "1"size: "1/2 Sem Gola"uniform_type: "Blazer"userid: "YS3ul395jBDcBf8I"__proto__: Object { … } uniform.php:307:13
```

Repare que o Objeto 33 está duplicado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

A seguintes linhas:

```
$rows[id]=$sonuc[id];
$rows[userid]=$sonuc[userid];
$rows[uniform_type]=$sonuc[uniform_type];
$rows[date]=$sonuc[date];
$rows[size]=$sonuc[model];
$rows[color]=$sonuc[color];
$rows[provider_id]=$sonuc[provider_id];
$rows[contract]=$sonuc[contract];
$rows[amount]=$sonuc[amount];
$rows[cost]=$sonuc[cost];
$rows[place]=$sonuc[place];
```

Estão atribuindo valores associativos no array `rows` e a linha:

```
array_push($rows,$sonuc);
```

Atribui valores indexados no array `rows`.

Presumo que a segunda opção seja seu objetivo, uma vez que a primeira opção sobrescreverá o valor anterior atribuído ao array `rows` a cada iteração; e por isso você só vê o 33 "repetido", pois ele é o último item da sua lista.

Para resolver seu problema basta remover as linhas que atribuem valores associativos:

```
while($sonuc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    array_push($rows,$sonuc);
}
```